# Map reduce for getting unique dataset between two collection

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

How to get a unique set of data between two collection using map reduce.

```
CollectionA   CollectionB
X, Y, Z        X, Y, Z
1, 2, 3        1, 4, 5
1, 4, 5
2, 6, 8
```

Objective is to list out unique data in collectionA. From example above, unique data in collection A is (1, 2,  3) and (2, 6, 8) when compared with collectionB

One thought I have is to select everything from collectionB and then compare with collectionA (collectionB size is going to be smaller than collectionA). But this didn't work for me.

Some sudo code would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

If one collections is much smaller than the other there is an elegant Mapreduce solution. (I got it from 'Hadoop in Practice'). You can run a map-only job in which you work on the records of Collection A while you add the collection B to the `DistributedCache`. Then a map task processes a number of records each comparing them with every B-record in the cache, this way you can leave out the sort and reduce steps in your algorithm.